# Two different datagridview rows getting selected when one should be selected

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with winform project. i have two datagridview which has same number of columns and same structure. frist column is checkbox column.

here is code to bind two datagrid with same kind of data.

```
List<AllGroupNames> grpDtl = GetAllGroups(Nodes);
List<AllGroupNames> grpDtl1 = GetAllGroups(Nodes); //grpDtl.GetRange(0, grpDtl.Count);

//bind two grid with all groups name
if (_grpDtl != null && _grpDtl.Count > 0)
{
    dgSingleGroups.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgSingleGroups.DataSource = grpDtl;
    dgSingleGroups.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Select";
    dgSingleGroups.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "GroupName";
    dgSingleGroups.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
    dgSingleGroups.Columns[0].Width = 47;
    dgSingleGroups.Columns[1].Width = 346;

    dgAllGroups.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgAllGroups.DataSource = grpDtl1;
    dgAllGroups.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Select";
    dgAllGroups.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "GroupName";
    dgAllGroups.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
    dgAllGroups.Columns[0].Width = 47;
    dgAllGroups.Columns[1].Width = 346;
}

grpDtl1 = null;
grpDtl = null;
_grpDtl = null;
```

**GetAllGroups()** iterate in treeview node collection and accumulate node name.

```
private List<AllGroupNames> GetAllGroups(TreeNodeCollection tnCollection)
        {
            //accumulate group name in recursive fashion
            foreach (TreeNode tn in tnCollection)
            {
                if (tn.Tag != null)
                {
                    if (((object)tn.Tag).GetType().ToString().Contains("TunerDetails"))
                    {
                        _grpDtl.Add(new AllGroupNames { Select = false, GroupName = tn.Text });
                    }
                    GetAllGroups(tn.Nodes);
                }
            }
            return _grpDtl;
        }
```

Now problem is when i check second grid checkbox then my first grid checkbox is getting checked invisibly means when i am reading first grid's first column value in loop then i am getting checkbox value true. where as i have not checked my first grid's any checkbox.

when i select any row of second grid that same row is getting automatically selected in first grid.

[image]

**I just select one row from right side grid and same row of left side grid automatically gets selected....which is problem for me. Why two grid syncing automatically.** screen shot attached.

why it is happening i am not able to capture the reason. please help me what to change in code to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Remove `_grpDtl` from where you're declaring it now and make `GetAllGroups()` return a new collection of `AllGroupNames` when it's called.

Comment: You are binding both data grids to the same DataSource object, so when you make a change in one DataGrid, that change is reflected in the DataSource, which also is attached to the other DataGrid. You need separate data sources for each data grid.

Comment: Thanks both of you pointed me to right direction. problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently every object of class `AllGroupName` has a Boolean property `Select`.

You created Column[0] such, that the checkbox is checked whenever this boolean is true, and vice versa: whenever the operator checks this checkbox, the corresponding AllGroupName.Select will become true.

You decided to use the same DataSource as object in two DataGridViews.

- Operator checks the checkbox of row[4] in Dgv1
- This means that DataSource[4].Select = true;
- This means that all objects that have this DataSource will be notified that [4] has changed
- Row[4] in Dgv1 and Dgv2 will be updated: checkbox is checked.

If you don't want that changes in Dgv1 are refelected in Dgv2, then you should make a copy of the datasource.

```
List<...> data1 = ...;                      // shouldn't this be an BindingList<...> ?
Dgv1.DataSource = data1;  
List<...> data2 = new List<...>(data1);     // clone data1
Dgv2.DataSource = data2;
```